# Unable to install iis manager on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, iis

I get an error while trying to install IIS manager from "Turn on off windows features" on a windows 8 machine. Just before trying to install this I installed Visual Studio 2013 community online and rebooted my machine. Visual Studio works fine.

I also made sure all updates are installed on my machine and also rebooted and tried installing IIS manager.

The error that I get is "The function attempted to use a name that is reserved for use by another transaction"

Thanks

Ranjith

Comment: copy the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS to the desktop, zip the folder, upload the zip to a cloud service like OneDrive or dropbox and post a link here.